# designing ListBox.ItemTemplate contents using expression blend?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, user-interface, expression-blend

I'm working on a project which requires its `listBox.ItemTemplate` to be neat, so I tried to design it out with a new page, then using expression blend to drag it into a ListBox.  However, it turns into "destroyed" ui. What should I know in order to design `ListBox.ItemTemplate` content in xaml with expression blend?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Expression blend allows to design item templates right in `ListBox`.

Created template should looks like:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!-- Layout here -->
        <DataTemplate>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
<ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this very detailed article on *CodeProject* on how to define and style the ItemTemplate for a ListBox: [**ListBox styling - Additional templates in Expression Blend**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79291/ListBox-Styling-Part-3-Additional-Templates-in-Exp). It is for Silverlight in general but the principle will be the same for WP7 (as this is a subset of Silverlight). Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

To create a custom `ListBox` see the following [Microsoft tutorial](http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/ee942883). Also, to import/inherit a control from VS2010 you could follow the methods outlined in [part 1](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/wp7-tutorial-8-creating-a-custom-button-in-expression-blend-1) and [part 2](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/wp7-tutorial-9-creating-a-custom-button-in-expression-blend-part-2) of a tutorial provided by TheWindowsClub.

There were tutorials by Microsoft, but I have check my favourites list and they have been taken down for some strange reason. Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I've been searching for the solution for 2 hours and this is the solution:

[**Editing ListBoxItem styles and templates**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj709919.aspx)

if it seems too complicated, I'll write a blog post about it in one week, I'll share it.